# Mass renaming using Python

Tags: python, file, file-rename

Say I have a bunch of files on one directory, with different extensions:

```
dsgxy7wusshg2.jpg
ds65321333321.png
ds2716113shg2.jpg
d3171763462g2.jpg
5432125321hg2.png
db37fv73v7av1.png
d0zhzb38b22g2.jpg
d3171763462nb.jpg
```

I would like to create a small script that will rename every file to the format `mystring_x.ext`, where `mystring` is a string that I set in the script, `x` is the number of the file being renamed, and `ext` would be the **original** extension of the file. It should not be possible to have two files using the same number, with different extensions. Only one file per number.

I understand I should use the `os` module to rename files, but what procedure should I try and use to do this task?

Comment: Does the order matter? Also, what Martijn said ;) We won't write a complete solution for you

Comment: Nothing -- all I can think of right now is using `while True` to rename each file, but I don't know how to set `x` for each file.

Comment: The order of files does not matter, but the number order does.

Comment: @user1417933: *How* does it matter? Files have no natural order.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your meaning of order. They need to be sequential, as in there is a file_1, file_2, like that. It doesn't matter which file is which.

Comment: @user1417933: Okay, that answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
directory = '/path/to/dir'
base = 'mystring'

for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(directory), 1):
    ext = f.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    absolutify = lambda s: os.path.join(directory, s)
    os.rename(absolutify(f), absolutify('%s_%d.%s' % (base, i, ext)))
```

Comment: The extension need to be the same as the original one, how would this be done?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rsplice'`

Comment: @user1417933: Oh, typo. It's `rsplit`

Comment: Ran it. It works okay, but no matter which directory I chose, after it finishes it moves all the contents to the directory where the script is ran from - any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @user: Yeah, that's another fail on my side... Check the edit

Comment: Maybe you should also include a check so you don't overwrite existing files by accident.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works great now. One thing though for future uses, it seems to start at 0, is there any way to prevent this and make it always start with 1?

Comment: @user: Yeah, just add `1` as an additional argument to `enumerate`. Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: Gezz User*, can you do any work yourself? What did you even learn from this? I think you did a fine Job Niklas, but you did way to much work for him.

Comment: @John: Yeah, I figured that too. I'd appreciate an upvote though ;)